# How do I get grep color in the file names before each match?

Tags: unix, colors, grep

If I run `grep -ir "somethingtomatch" .` from the current directory, I typically get results like this:

```
./some/path/file1.html: filecontent filecontent keyword filecontent
./some/path/file2.html: filecontent filecontent filecontent keyword
./some/path/file3.html: filecontent keyword filecontent filecontent
./some/path/file4.html: keyword filecontent filecontent filecontent
```

I used `grep --color=auto -ir 'somethingtomatch" .` but it only highlights the keywords in white on a red highlight. I'm trying to get file names on the left color-coded too.  How do I do that?

I'm using Terminal.app in OS X with bash and xterm (and I tried xterm-color too).

Answer (score 7):

You can change the colors with the $GREP_COLORS environment variable. In your case, you could try to `export GREP_COLORS='fn=1;32'` to change the color of the filename to green.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I tried:  
`export TERM=xterm-color`  
`export GREP_COLORS='fn=1;32'`  
`grep --color=auto -ir 'keyword' .`

Comment: Ok, it seems like you're suffering under "Terminal.app". I don't know much about it, but maybe this [link](http://www.amateurtopologist.com/2010/04/27/making-terminal-app-suck-less/) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to postprocess the output.  Something like this might work:

```
$ grep --color -ir 'pattern' files | perl -pe 's/^([^:]+):/chomp(my $f = `ls --color \Q$1`); $f/e'
```

(I'm assuming you're displaying output from a Linux system, since OSX `ls` doesn't colorize files usefully for this.)

(NB:  the distinction between this answer and the `$GREP_COLORS` one is that the latter uses a fixed color, whereas mine queries `ls --color`.)

Comment: OSX can colorize files using `ls -G`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ack, which allows you to set environment variables for filename, line number and the match itself.

http://betterthangrep.com/